# What is the integral of the Dirac delta function between these limits?

Tags: definite-integrals, dirac-delta

I've learnt that $\displaystyle\int_{-k}^k\delta(x)dx=1$ where $k$ is any positive real number. But what is $\displaystyle\int_{-k}^0\delta(x)dx$?

Comment: Integration of $\delta(x)$ on any interval where $0$ is not an endpoint is well-defined.  But (remember $\delta$ is not a genuine function, only a distribution), your case with endpoint $0$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The integral of dirac delta is the heaviside step function, $H(x)$.

The step function is basically $0$, but if $x$ is postive, then $1$.

Using half-maximum convention, the integral would be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Using regular convention, just $0$, because $H(0)-H(-k)=0-0=0.$

So it depends on what value of $H(0)$ you use.